# faster way to INSERT a combination into a table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Started my database for a mock hotel exercise. Need to insert a room for every check_in, checkout_date. a small sample like this is no prob but for a hotel with 30+ rooms I'd go insane. How does one insert a list of rooms into an interval like the days in a month or even a year?

```
 booking
id  check_in    check_out    guest_id, room_id
 ----------------------------
1, '05/10/2018', 05/11/2018, null, 101 
2, '05/10/2018', 05/11/2018, null, 102 
3, '05/10/2018', 05/11/2018, null, 103 
4, '05/11/2018', 05/12/2018, null, 101 
5, '05/11/2018', 05/12/2018, null, 102
6, '05/11/2018', 05/12/2018, null, 103 


room
room_id price
----------------------------
 101  $68
 102  $68
 103  $90 

guest
guest_id name
---------------------------
32  tony stark
33  iron man
34  robert downey
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are you typing these out by hand or something?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I started to type the bookings table by hand it then realized it'd take forever. one solution I've done is wrote a script that would create the insert values in ruby. i was just wondering if there are other methods that don't require another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `generate_series()` function to loop over your date range:

```
insert into booking (check_in, check_out, room_id)
  select
    generate_series('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', '1 day'::interval)::date,
    generate_series('2018-01-02', '2019-01-01', '1 day'::interval)::date,
    101;
```

Note that if all your check-ins are one day then you don't need both `check_in` *and* `check_out` fields in your table.

If you want to do this for all rooms, you can cross join on the rooms table:

```
insert into booking (room_id, check_in, check_out)
  select room_id, check_in, check_in + interval '1 day'
  from room
  cross join generate_series('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', interval '1 day') as check_in;
```

Comment: ahh nice! I figured there was a way to do it easier. Would there perhaps be a way to generate with the list of rooms or am i asking for to much haha.

Comment: Truly appreciate your time here, just seeing the example has taught me so much. because of it I found an article similar to what you've done showing me some advanced tricks. although i don't understand it yet, I'm going to make it a goal to figure it out today. thank you

https://regilero.github.io/postgresql/english/2017/06/26/postgresql_advanced_generate_series/

Answer (score 1):

These options may not be the most efficient but they are some ways that I work these problems.

**Option 1**
Create a user interface that allows you to enter the information. I use PHP and create an interface that has forms that allows me to enter all of the information, and then submits it into my database.

So long as you have all your rooms, and rates. You need a form where you can select the room from a drop down. You can use this to get the room and rate. Then you enter the date range. Then you enter the guest. You can take all of the in a programming language like PHP and dump it into your database creating IDs that'll join it all together properly. (Depending on experience may be easier said than done).

**Option 2** 
Put the data into a spreadsheet and use import features on your sql management tool.

**Option 3**
This I utilize for things that aren't going to happen on a regular basis, one time data inserts. Using a spreadsheet tool create a CSV file, that way all the commas are added. You can copy and paste from a text editor the values. Then you can Find and Replace , with ',' and add parens where they need to go.

Comment: interesting thoughts, I actually did option 3 for my database, used ruby to return an array of arrays, then just find and replaced them. crude but effective. I'm just surprised there isn't an easier way in sql to do just this.

Comment: I'm looking at it, to see if you can construct it within a while loop maybe? Not sure how effective it would be.. But if you have a design in mind, and there is a good pattern to fall on... You may be able to do that..